# How to test AJAX in command line?

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, node.js

Suppose I have some code in `JavaScript`, which uses `jQuery.ajax` to call the server REST API.

In order to test it I would like to

- use a dummy HTTP server, which read responses from static XML files;
- run the `JavaScript` code "headless", i.e. without a browser;
- run all these tests in command line.

It looks like I can use `node.js` with an embedded dummy HTTP server. Does it make sense? Do you know any examples of such projects (in github or somewhere)?

Comment: Well, it makes sense, yes. `:)`

Comment: I haven't yet worked with headless browsers, so I wouldn't know how to do this, but I'm sure it's not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done something like this yet to be honest but I am evaluating the following approaches:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/

This is really interesting, I hope this link help you get started

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with using node.js for this is that it doesn't provide everything that a browser will provide … including XMLHttpRequest.

I'm in the process of developing a library (proprietary, for internal use only) that I'm trying to test with node.js.

My work around for the lack of XHR support is to use [this implementation of XHR](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest) in conjunction with some Microsoft provided code [to add backwards compatibility for the standard XHR to old IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx).

If you are using jQuery then you'll probably need to modify it as jQuery adds its own compatibility later for old IE.

The result looks like this:

```
var XMLHttpRequest;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
}
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined") {
    console.log("Undefined"); (function() {
        try {
            XMLHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
        } catch(e) {}
        try {
            XMLHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        } catch(e) {}
        try {
            XMLHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {}
        try {
            XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
        } catch(e) {}
        //Microsoft.XMLHTTP points to Msxml2.XMLHTTP and is redundant
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined") {
            throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
        }
    })();
};
```

Beyond that, running a simple HTTP server in your test suite is the usual approach for this sort of problem. I haven't got as far as implementing that yet and am working off an httpd running on a test server.